What is causing the regular 10 second oscillation of my WIFI speeds (internally inside my network)?
I have been trying to get the optimal setup for wireless VR and as a result found this issue with my network setup. For some odd reason I get this EXACT 10 second oscillation where the speed jumps up and then slowly ramps down and then jumps back up again. I've included an image of openspeedtest testing between 2 devices in my network. I also included an image of the network graph in resource monitor during this test.
I have tried isolating every single piece of hardware in my network (this is about internal network speed, not internet). I get the same issue in varying degrees between all devices, I have used 2 different routers, tested between 2 android devices to rule out a network adapter issue on my PC, tested with my internet completely disconnected, looked through all possible settings in my routers, manually switched channels and channel widths, tried without ax, ac only, tried toggling OFDMA and TWT. I've tried probably anything you can think of within my power, for example I don't have access to a second wired machine but I did have a friend run the openspeedtest server so I could see if the issue persisted without wifi. This show me there is still a regular 10 second interference but very minimal when not on wifi but it seems this blip is related to whatever is causing my wifi issue.
It happens on all bands (2.4/5/6 GHz) and all channels, I haven't found any way to reliably stop this from happening, it stopped by itself when I physically moved my router from one side of the room to the other and then started again 20 minutes later so this was likely unrelated. I try cooling my router in case it was an overheating issue. I tried in a different room, I tried turning off all wireless devices in my home, I tried a faraday box around my router in case of interference.
My two routers are TP Link's AX1500 and AXE5400
image showing oscillationanother image showing oscillation

+1 clear explanation of issue. BTW, when moving router, it likely caused it to restart, getting an IP from ISP, again... another area of inquiry. Is ISP capping limit?

Only one of your devices supports Wifi6E. How busy is the 2.4Ghz and 5.0Ghz spectrum? What type of devices do you have connected to your network. I recall watching a video on YouTube where the individual was dealing with wireless speakers that would constantly change channels by themselves

@DrMoishePippik I've actually done these tests while fully disconnected from internet too and yes I did unplug the router to move it across the room. In retrospect it seems like that was just a coincidence that it stopped then, I can't say for certain either way though.

@Ramhound 2.4Ghz is very busy, 5Ghz less so, my neighbours are pretty much all on non DFS channels, 100+ is clear almost all the time, very occasionally one SSID will pop there for a few minutes then move away. 6Ghz is clear too, I sideloaded Wifianalyzer into my Quest.

Regular oscillation seems to me to indicate some electromagnetic interference. Large appliances can produce this sort of interference, but you can also usually easily observe them: fan motors on the central heat/air, dryer motor, etc. Other causes could be harder to observe. If you're nearby to an airfield or military base there may be radio transmissions you cannot so easily observe or track, or a neighbor running amateur radio equipment or other relatively high powered radio frequency transmitters. For these, trying different channels is probably, effectively, the best option.
